# How to set slideshow for both Background and Lockscreen using Powershell script?

Tags: powershell, intune

I have several images that is needed to deploy as slideshow for both Lockscreen and Background (Windows Background) to selected staff over Intune. How do I use powershell script to do that? Have attempted the following script for background slideshow but my background just turns black

```
# Set the directory path to your folder of images
$SlideshowFolder = "C:pathtofolder"

# Set the slideshow duration (in seconds)
$SlideshowDuration = 10  # 30 minutes

# Set the transition type (0 for no transition, 1 for fade)
$TransitionType = 1

# Configure the desktop background settings
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Control Panel\Desktop' -Name Wallpaper - 
Value ""
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Control Panel\Desktop' -Name 
WallpaperStyle -Value 6
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Control Panel\Desktop' -Name TileWallpaper 
-Value 0
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Control Panel\Desktop' -Name 
WallpaperChangeInterval -Value $SlideshowDuration
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Control Panel\Desktop' -Name 
WallpaperTransition -Value $TransitionType

# Set the desktop background to the slideshow folder using 
SystemParametersInfo
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class PInvoke {
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern int SystemParametersInfo(int uAction, int uParam, string lpvParam, int fuWinIni);
}
"@

[PInvoke]::SystemParametersInfo(0x0014, 0, $SlideshowFolder, 0x01)

# Refresh the desktop to apply changes
RUNDLL32.EXE USER32.DLL,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters
```

Comment: Did you tried something?Please share your efforts.

Comment: Hi @mandy8055, thanks for responding. I have tried following various guides online but none were showing how to use multiple images as slideshow for both Background and Lockscreen using Powershell script. The closest that I have came across is this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1326152/add-multiple-pictures-lockscreen-slideshow-for-win, where it uses PSADT (PowerShell App Deployment Toolkit). However, after trying to install and run the program nothing happens and there is no error messages as well.

Comment: @mandy8055 As such, im trying to use solely powershell script instead of using PSADT or other 3rd party programs

Comment: Actually why I was asking is I am not sure how much you have achieved your requirement or where you got stuck. If I have to do it from scratch I would write the below script? Please let me know if it helped. Then I'll add it as an answer. I have added the comments as well. https://notepad.pw/ioivqUyAMG3W2VBzYhRw

Comment: Truly grateful for your help @mandy8055. for lockscreen it should be centrally managed by my IT as such im unable to change for now. However for background slideshow the script provided does not work as well, despite script run successfully. the Slideshowimages folder's path did appeared in "SlideshowDirectoryPath1" when I open "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Wallpapers" on Registry Key. "SlideshowSourceDirectoriesSet" value is also at "1".

Comment: Also, initially the path for Lockscreen doesnt exist and hence i added the following to the script:-----------            
# Create the PersonalizationCSP registry key if it does not exist. ----------------------------------------------
if (-Not (Test-Path "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Personalization")) {
    New-Item -Path HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Personalization -ItemType RegistryKey